# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, nuget-package

If I run "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata" commmand in the Package Manager Console I take this error.Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

i have faced the same issue while installing the Microsoft.AspNet.Odata version 6.0 . Since, i did not had any specific requirement for version 6.0 i have installed version 5.9.1 using the command **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -Version 5.9.1**. and it installed without any issues.If you too does not have any requirement for version 6 you can install 5.9.1 . I guess Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0 has some incompatibility issues with the .net version 4.5. Hope this helps